# HTTP error (401 - Unauthorized): Service not available, please try again later

Tags: centos, yum

I just install CentOS-8 (release no. is: 8.2.2004) and when I am trying to use the yum package manager (e.x for install or search packages) I am getting this message: "This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register."

Then when I try to register my system using subscription-manager I am getting this output:

```
[user@centos ~]$ sudo subscription-manager register --username myUserName --password a-password 
Registering to: subscription.rhsm.redhat.com:443/subscription
HTTP error (401 - Unauthorized): Service not available, please try again later
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

---

Thank you for your quick reply. I just apply your answer and still can't use the yum to install a package.

Here is an ls on my `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory.

```
[user@centos yum.repos.d]$ ls
CentOS-AppStream.repo   CentOS-Extras.repo      dgoodwin-subscription-manager-    epel-8.repo  fedora-rpmfusion.repo
centosbase.repo         CentOS-fasttrack.repo   epel-modular.repo                          fedora-russian.repo
CentOS-Base.repo        CentOS-HA.repo          epel-playground.repo                       getpagespeed-extras.repo
CentOS-centosplus.repo  CentOS-Media.repo       epel.repo                                  rpmfusion-free-updates.repo
CentOS-CR.repo          CentOS-PowerTools.repo  epel-testing-modular.repo                  rpmfusion-free-updates-testing.repo
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo   CentOS-Sources.repo     epel-testing.repo
CentOS-Devel.repo       CentOS-Vault.repo       fedora.repo
```

And here is my terminal output after I used yum install

```
[user@centos yum.repos.d]$ sudo yum install filezilla
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Last metadata expiration check: 0:04:09 ago on Tue 17 Nov 2020 08:43:19 PM EET.
=======================================================================
Some packages in your transaction are brought to you by GetPageSpeed: 
 - libuv-1:1.40.0-1.el8.x86_64
 - pugixml-1.10-1.el8.x86_64
To enable package installs, subscribe using the following link:

https://www.getpagespeed.com/repo-subscribe?server_ip=141.237.47.180
=======================================================================
```

What am I doing wrong? I am completely lost.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot subscribe a **Centos** server to **RHN**. You will need a RHEL distribution.
Once done you will need :

1. Register on the Red Hat Customer Portal.
2. Buy & Map a subscription to your RedHat Login ID.
3. Activate the subscription.
4. Attach the subscription to the server : `subscription-manager register`

**Since your last comment :**

Don't worry about the message telling you that the system is not registered ; It's just an info.

As I see you have to enable centos repositories so you can use a mirrors to download the needed packages you can configure them with yum only :

Create `centosbase.repo` file under `/etc/yum.repos.d/` and populate it with the above :

```
[base]
name=CentOS $releasever – Base
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1

[updates]
name=CentOS $releasever – Updates
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1

[extras]
name=CentOS $releasever – Extras
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Clean yum cache :

```
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/*
yum clean all
```

Then install your packages :

```
yum install <package_name>
```

If your system stucks at the warning message during `yum install`, then cleanup subscription-manger :

```
subscription-manager clean all
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not want to  subscribe a Centos server to RHN. I just download and install CentOS8 from centos.org/downloads and when I did try to install an app using the yum I got this message on terminal and on my system logs: "This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register."  Then I did your number 1 option (Register on the Red Hat Customer Portal.) and used the subscription-manager as the logs said and the continue is on my fist post. My problem is that I can't use the yum. Any solution on that?

Comment: I have made an edit !

Comment: Don't forget please to make it as resolved if this helped you !

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I reinstalled CentOS 8 and the problem just solved. Maybe something went wrong during the initial installation.